# Inner join two query and alias

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I want to inner join two set from two query. But it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
(select model from PC) T1
inner join (select model from Laptop) T2
on T1.model = T2.model
```

It appear error on two alias T1, T2

Pls help me

@deanosaur: Here is schema:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxTOy.jpg

Comment: I'm reticent to answer this outright as a minimal amount of research would show you several things wrong.

Comment: I don't know what your mean. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: It means you don't seem to have put enough effort into solving the problem yourself before asking for help. I would also add that your question isn't very clear either. Do you want to match a single column of one query against a single column of the other query? Please show an example: data samples of `PC` and `Laptop` (or, perhaps the results of `T1` and `T2`) and the desired result of the join.

Comment: If you have no better understanding of SQL than this, you have no business even considering querying a database. The structure of a selct statmenet is datbase 101 - day one. If you don't know immediately what is wrong with this stement you don't have theconceptual understanding to ever correctly query a database. If someone working for me came to me with something this messed up, I would know I needed to fire them. You don't even have minimal beginner skils.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it gets you closer to what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM PC T1 INNER JOIN LAPTOP T2 ON T1.model=T2.model;
```

Comment: I see your answer right but it not my need. I want to use inner join for two querry.
And here field of laptop and PC is different just same some field, so you dont use select * .

Comment: It would help if you could post an example of PC and LAPTOP and the result you would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select T1.model
from PC T1 inner join Laptop T2
on T1.model = T2.model
```